# ListView doesn't show results but passes through code

Tags: android, android-widget

I have row for ListView(listview is inside LinearLayout) like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtChoice"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chk"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

and Adapter like inner class

```
private class SimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String[] list=null;

    public SimpleAdapter(String[] list) {
      this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return list.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
      return list[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return list[position].hashCode();
    }

    // Generate view for coupon's row 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      View view = convertView;

      if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
      }    

      return view;
    } 
  }
```

and I set adapter like

```
        SimpleAdapter m=new SimpleAdapter( data );
            listView.setAdapter(m);
```

data is `String[] data=new String[]{"test","test_1"};`
but list doesn;t show anything. I debuged, it passes normaly but nothing to show. What can be problem ?

Comment: where you are using list object in getView()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the same code you posted in question, I have tried it.
and that run perfectly..

i have used the same adapter class in my activity and xml

in my TestThis.java file

i used your Adapter class and also
i have written,

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.maintwiter);

        String[] data=new String[]{"test","test_1"};
        SimpleAdapter m=new SimpleAdapter( data );
        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setAdapter(m); 
        setContentView(listView);
    }
```

**But Still You need to set the data from the String array to your text views in getView() method**

Man it gave me the result as list with 2 row.

[image: this]

Answer (score 2):

I think your getView() needs some work.  You're not really doing anything with the data you've passed in.  Try this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v;
    if (convertView == null)
        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    else
        v = convertView;

    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txChoice);
    text.setText( list[position] );     

    return v;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  View view = convertView;

  if(view == null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
  }    

  return view;
}
```

modify your getView with this:

```
  if(convertView == null){
    LayoutInflater inflater (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
  }   TextView t = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(your text view); t.setText(...); return convertView;
```

here to inflate the row you do not set the content of row.. use the convertiview to retrive your text view, call getItem with the position passed as parameter to the getView method, and set your text.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

          ViewHolder holder;

          if(view == null)
          {
                   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                   holder = new ViewHolder();

                   holder.txtChoice=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtChoice);                 

          }
          else
                   holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();     

          holder.textChoice.setText(lis[position]));    

          return view;
        }

        static class ViewHolder
        {       
            TextView txtChoice;        
        }
```